# Set null value to disabled text box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core

I have some questions regarding how to set the null value to a disabled text box and pass the null value to the database using jQuery. Right now, I am able to enable or disable the text box using checkbox function but I can't figure it out on how can I pass the null value if the text box is disabled. Below is the code that I think related to the problem.

script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#CheckBox1').change(function () {
        $("#TextBox1").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });

}); </script>
```

Model class

```
 [Display(Name = "Login Restriction")]
 public bool isRestrictedIp { get; set; }

 [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid IP address format")]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is a mandatory field.")]
 [Display(Name = "Restrict IP Address to")]
 [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = " The {0} cannot exceed {1} characters.")]
 public string restrictedIp { get; set; }
```

the checkbox and text box code

```
<div class="form-group form-check">
     <label class="form-check-label">
         <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="isRestrictedIp" id="CheckBox1" checked="checked" /> 
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.isRestrictedIp)
     </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
     <label asp-for="restrictedIp" class="control-label"></label>
     <input asp-for="restrictedIp" class="form-control" id="TextBox1" />
     <span asp-validation-for="restrictedIp" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not send disabled input to server, so you need to use tricks like this.

**View**:

Declare `TextBox1_Display` input to display.

```
 <label asp-for="TextBox1_Display" class="control-label"></label>
 <input asp-for="restrictedIp" class="form-control" id="TextBox1" type="hidden" />   
 <input asp-for="restrictedIp" class="form-control" id="TextBox1_Display" />
 <span asp-validation-for="restrictedIp" class="text-danger"></span>
```

**Jquery**

```js
var $TextBox1 = $("#TextBox1");
var $TextBox1_Display = $("#TextBox1_Display");

$('#CheckBox1').change(function () {
    var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $TextBox1_Display.prop("disabled", !isChecked);
    
    $TextBox1.val(isChecked ? $TextBox1_Display.val() : "");
    
    console.log($("#TextBox1").val());
});

$TextBox1_Display.keyup(function(){
   $TextBox1.val($(this).val());
   console.log($TextBox1.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" asp-for="isRestrictedIp" id="CheckBox1" checked="checked" />

<label asp-for="TextBox1_Display" class="control-label"></label>
 <input asp-for="restrictedIp" class="form-control" id="TextBox1" type="hidden" />   
 <input asp-for="restrictedIp" class="form-control" id="TextBox1_Display" />
 <span asp-validation-for="restrictedIp" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Edit: Add AllowEmptyString to the model class then we are good to go.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage ="Invalid IP address format")]
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true, ErrorMessage = "This is a mandatory field.")]
[Display(Name = "Restrict IP Address to")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = " The {0} cannot exceed {1} characters.")]
public string restrictedIp { get; set; }
```

Comment: ok..i will try it first.. will let you know if this solve the problem..10QVM...

Comment: may I know where is TextBox1_Display come from?is it kind of jQuery syntax..sorry for this silly question but I relatively new to jQuery..I've tried the code but the textbox is not changed whenever i checked the checkbox

Comment: I've just updated my answer. You add one more input `TextBox1_Display` to display, while `TextBox1` is `hidden` type to send to server

Comment: i already try it.  At first checked, it did change the textbox  but whenever i unchecked the checkbox, the textbox does not change after that. I am not sure why is that happening..

Comment: I've just updated my answer with the demo, please take a look at @Fafau

Comment: it solved the checkbox issue..but when i press submit button, it seems like it does not get the null value because the error message (from the modal class) "This is a mandatory field." appeared.

Comment: ok.. i have found what I did wrong..I need to declare allow nullstring in the model class as follow.. 

'[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true, ErrorMessage = "This is a mandatory field.")]'

anyway, thanks for your help. I will mark this as answer.